# Cookie Overflow in Rails 4 even with memcachd server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm converting a Rails 3 app, which used `active_record_store` for storing session information that was too large for regular cookies, to Rails 4, which has deprecated active_record_store. My Rails 4 app is raising the error...

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow):
```

that caused me to switch to `active_record_store` in Rails 3. What can I do in Rails 4 if my session information exceeds the allowable limits?

Update. I started the memcache server on my local machine and configured it like so in the development file

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, 'localhost', '127.0.0.1:11211',
{:namespace => 'myapp123'}
```

In the console, when I do Rails.cache, it shows this (followed by a lot of data)

=> true

```
>> Rails.cache
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore:0x007f80ebe10500 @options={}, @data=#<Dalli::Client:0x007f80ebe0fd08 @servers=["localhost:11211"]
```

However I'm getting the same error when I'm running the application

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow):
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:455:in `[]='
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:109:in `set_cookie'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:350:in `commit_session'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1963944942928963409__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only store 4kb in session if you are using cookie store. You have two options.

1. Look at reducing the information you are storing in session. If you are storing a model object in session, change it to store just the id.
2. Use mem_cache_store

   config.action_controller.session_store = :mem_cache_store

Also you need to setup a mem cache server and configure it as below:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, 'localhost', '127.0.0.1:11211',
{:namespace => 'myapp123'}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error even though I've started a mem cache server and configured it as you suggested. I'll post the error in an update to the OP.

Comment: It seems to still use cookies store... What is in your config/initializers/session_store.rb file

Answer (score 1):

Can you show me the content of config/initializers/session_store.rb seems like you still use the cookie store there.

When you define the cache store, you still have to change the session_store

```
config.session_store = :mem_cache_store
```